# QTableView displays column headers, but no data?

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, model-view

I can't figure out why my QTableView won't display any data. I've searched all other questions about this problem and it seems the problem is usually someone trying to create the model on the stack and letting it go out of scope...

I am creating the model on the heap so this is not the problem, yet I still get no data in the View. The column headers from my sql table are shown correctly. What could be wrong with this code?

```
// db is my database wrapper and database returns a reference to the database
QSqlTableModel *tradeHistoryModel = new QSqlTableModel(this, db->database());

// table_tradeHistory is my QTableView created elsewhere
table_tradeHistory->setModel(tradeHistoryModel);

tradeHistoryModel->setTable("mytrades");
tradeHistoryModel->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit);

if (!tradeHistoryModel->select())
{
  // err is just a handy macro for displaying fancy error output
  // the call to select does NOT return false so this never gets called
  err("model select failed!");
}

// debug is another macro, the output shows 200 rows (which is correct)
debug(QString("Got %1 rows..").arg(tradeHistoryModel->rowCount()));
```

So there is no error shown because select() returns true, and the debug output shows the model selected all 200 rows, but still no data appears in the View...

Thanks for any help!

Edit: This must have been a Qt or Qt Designer bug... I went back into designer and "morphed" the QTableView into a QTreeView, then switched it back and now all of a sudden it is showing the data... I did not change any of the code when I did this... wtf? If it is a bug I'm not sure I can reproduce it again...

Comment: table_tradeHistory->show() ??

Comment: The table is there along with the header labels pulled from the db table , it just wasn't showing any data... but I think it was a bug.

Comment: What is one supposed to do with a stackoverflow question that turns out to be a strange unexplained bug? If this was a bug report I'd close it as invalid...

Comment: @user1390471 I think you should write up your workaround as an answer and accept it. I just spent all day pulling my hair out over the same issue. I saw your final comment in your question, gave it a shot, and it worked for me. A successful workaround to a real bug (that apparently has been around for years) is a very useful answer!

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be the tradeHistoryModel->select(). I don't
 think it is selected properly. Try to call it separately, not on a IF statement. Also check the compatibility of the data, the data on the db and that on the QTableView. I had a similar problem with QDate and I managed to solve it after modifying the format it was displayed on the QTableView. The problem was PostgreSQL and Qt uses different date format.
To be sure it has nothing to do with this problem try

```
model->setFilter(filter);
model->select();
```

or

```
modelsql->removeColumn(0);
```

to remove a column that might contain this problem. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the heads up I'm sure that issue would have got me eventually! For now I'm using plain old mysql date formats so I haven't had a problem with that yet. Turns out it was some strange qt/designer/ui bug though...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the post. The same thing happened to me, and morphing the QTableView into a QTreeView and then back to a QTableView also fixed it for me. When I compared before and after, the original bad ui had the section `<attribute name="verticalHeaderDefaultSectionSize"><number>0</number></attribute>`. Maybe that made the header expand to the entire space of the view, and with no space to show rows of data, Qt had no reason to request data from the model.
I started with a QTableWidget but later switched to a QTableView to implement batching through canFetchMore/fetchMore, so maybe this problem is something left over from the QTableWidget.